# Is low humidity bad for HIPOT testing electrical harnesses?

Tags: cables, testing, humidity, hipot

From what I understand for HIPOT testing high humidity could be a potential issue because if cable insulators absorb moisture that could affect their resistance.

What about low humidity? Is there any reason why low humidity would be bad for HIPOT testing? Most cables aren't ESD sensitive which is why you usually would want to have a minimum humidity requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disadvantage in testing your electrical harnesses in a low-humidity ambient is that you will not evaluate the potential for the insulating materials contained in your harnesses to leak current when exposed to moisture.

Ideally, the components are tested under the worst-case operating conditions.  In HIPOT testing, the worst-case is at the high-end of the humidity range.

There is no parasitic conduction path that is revealed at the low-humidity limit.  So in conclusion, there is no reason to test your electrical harnesses at the low-humidity limit.

Comment: That would make sense to me. These particular components are going to be used in the space environment where humidity will be very low. So I think for us it would make sense to test under lower humidity conditions.